# J2EE webapp Utilities project best practises

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

I have a Maven based J2EE project structure

```
Customer (root pom)
   |
   |------ WebTier (JSF 2/Primefaces)
   |
   |------ BusinessTier (EJB 3.*, interfaces, interface impl)
   |
   |------ PersistenceTier (JPA 2)
   |
   |------ CustomerEar
```

Now I have found that I'd need a new Java class or classes for handling basic routines
I guess its not good idea to place this Utility class under WebTier, because Utilities might be used also from BusinessTier. 
Is it the "best practise" to create an independent Java Project, implement necessary classes and include this jar to the ear??

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to try and justify a "best practice" in this kind of situation as it is a very project-specific question.

There would be nothing inherently wrong with adding a "CommonLibrary" project or such-like that is a dependency of both the WebTier and BusinessTier. In fact the project I am working on now is almost exactly that structure (with a common library).

As this is a maven project, just make sure the "CommonLibrary" project dependecy scope is set to "provided" in the Business/Web/Persistence tiers, and "compile" in the ear project.

e.g. In WebTier, the dependency would be:

```
<dependency>
   <groupID>group.name</groupID>
   <artifactID>common-library</artifactID>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: The scope would be 'provided' in the Web Tier as it would be a .war. The other tiers would be jars so the scope can be 'compile' for the persistence and business tiers.

Comment: you cant have jar scope as provided, since this is neither provided by the jdk nor server at runtime

Comment: Thanks @pappu_kutty, I have updated the description. I was only thinking about the WebTier.

Comment: @rusty_turkey I created new maven project with archetype maven-archetype-quickstart and included this jar into ear with necessary dependencies. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience , i recommend to have separate project folder for utility and include this as jar where ever is required

advantages are

1. easy maintenance, since you need to change code once .
2. plugin & unplug when ever you need.
3. you can have this as common and utilize for
   other projects.

for instance

apache string util

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

bean util

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. I'll investigate both suggestions